# free dimension of a module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

For any module $M$ there is defined the projective/injective/flat dimension, which is the length of the shortest projective/injective/flat resolution of $M$.

Why isn't there defined a *free dimension* of $M$, by $$\inf\{n\!\in\!\mathbb{N};\; \exists\text{free resolution }0\rightarrow F_n\rightarrow F_{n-1}\rightarrow\ldots\rightarrow F_0\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0\}.$$

Comment: The projective dimension is identical to the free dimension except perhaps when $M$ is projective. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27406/free-resolution-dimension